# connection manager in integration Services

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to create connection managers in my package and i need these to be dynamic

example: if i deploy package in UAT it should  be getting connection manager for UAT environment 
similar fashion it should map to corresponding  environments where ever am deploying it

Note :I am using Sql 2008R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to achieve this is by using "Package Configuration".
Please read the below to find out more and how you can implement it:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc895212.aspx

Comment: Appreciated for your quick response it help me i can see lot of different type of configurations in the article

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SSIS Package Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682(v=sql.105).aspx)

I mostly use the `SQL Server table` option.

**SQL Server SSIS Configuration Type**

> If you select the SQL Server configuration type, you specify the
>   connection to the SQL Server database in which you want to store the
>   configurations. You can save the configurations to an existing table
>   or create a new table in the specified database. The following SQL
>   statement shows the default CREATE TABLE statement that the Package
>   Configuration Wizard provides.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SSIS Configurations]
(
ConfigurationFilter NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ConfiguredValue NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
PackagePath NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ConfiguredValueType NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Appreciated for your quick response it help me